# How to test vector equality in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I wish to test if a vector has only three elements (0, 1, and NA).  How?  Suppose I have the vector "blarg" below.

**How do I test if another vector "foo" has exactly the elements of "blarg" (but without regard to order)?**

```
> blarg <- c(0, 1, NA)
> blarg
[1]  0  1 NA
> str(blarg)
num [1:3] 0 1 NA
```

Whoops, this returns a vector:

```
> foo <- c(0, 1, NA)
> foo %in% blarg
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This test does something, but it's wrong:

```
if (max(c(foo, 2) %in% blarg)) { print("ok") }
"ok"
```

I could do "if 0 in .. and 1 in .. and ..", but that seems ugly.

Comment: There are no lists in your question. Do you mean `vector`? You also do not have all of the variables defined. What is `blarg`?

Comment: Have you heard of MWE perhaps?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Right you are, so I defined blarg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my guess at what the OP is after:

```
blarg = c(0,1,NA)

setequal(blarg, c(0,1,NA))   # TRUE
setequal(blarg, c(0,1,2,NA)) # FALSE
```

If you care not only about values matching, but also positions, use `all.equal`.

Comment: `identical` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/identical could also be useful here

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `all` ( notthat I invert the order here):

```
all(blarg %in% c(0, 1, NA))
```

Another option :

```
unique(balrg)  %in%  c(0, 1, NA)
```

### edit:

If you have a list , you should `unlist` before applying this solution.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem to work, "all(blarg %in% c(0, 1, NA, 2))" returns TRUE. I think I could do this plus "&& length(blarg) == 3".

Comment: @dfrankow really? waht is your blarg here?

Comment: I just defined blarg above. I want to test vector equality, that the two sides are the same values.